# How to loop through array on click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of quotes and when clicking a button, I'd like it to fade out into a new quote randomly.

In the code below, instead of fading out into the next randomly chosen value in the array, it fades out completely and doesn't show another value when you click the button.

```
var quotes = [
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
 ]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#quoteDisplay').fadeOut('slow');
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
  });
});
```

Comment: you're not fading it back in

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `$('#quoteDisplay').fadeIn('slow');` after you've changed the element's text, also for the text to change only after the text has faded out entirely you should add your logic to a separate function and add it as a callback to the `fadeOut` function.
I've added an example below.

```js
var quotes = [
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
 ]

$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeAndDisplayMessage() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    $('#quoteDisplay').fadeIn();
  }
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#quoteDisplay').fadeOut('slow',changeAndDisplayMessage);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='button' class='btn' value='Generate Random Message'> </input>
  <h4 id='quoteDisplay'> Message will show here </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After you have inserted the innerHTML you will need to fade in the qouteDisplay dom element.

```
var quotes = [
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
 ]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#quoteDisplay').fadeOut('slow');
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    $('#quoteDisplay').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his issue. Once you click it fades out, displays, then fades in, uncleanly.

Comment: What do you mean by uncleanly. Please read his question and then downvote it. Just because you have the ability to down vote doesn't make your right.

Comment: I already did read his question, and your answer causes an issue when tested. As I stated.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

So you have to fadeout, when *complete* put the new text and fade in again:

EDIT: Example is in coffee script, my plain JavaScript times are long ago, it's just to point the direction:

```
$qd=$('#quoteDisplay')
$gd.fadeOut(complete: =>
    $qd.text(quotes[randomNumber])
    $gd.fadeIn()
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use ES6 when answering basic JS/jQuery questions, it can be confusing for new users, you should also try to maintain the same sintax and variables' names used in the given example code.